# Displaying information for controls from a List inside a List

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, foreach

I am trying to display all the list of steps as a progress bar and then listing all the form fields below for each step.  Getting the list of steps is easy.  I have a foreach loop that iterates through the Steps list.  However, when i try to do a foreach inside the list of steps, I get an error stating Fields Object is null.

```
iterates through with no issue but fails at getting the Fields Count:
@foreach (var step in Model.FormAttributes.Steps){
<li>@step.Fields.Count()</li>   }



    {
      "FormName": "Engagement Technology Request Form",
      "FormAttributes": {
      "Steps": [
      {
        "StepNumber": 1,
        "StepName": "Engagement Details",
        "Fields": [
        {
           "type": "text",
           "field-name": "txtBillCode",
           "field-text": "Bill/Matter Code",
           "required": true
         },
      {
        "type": "text",
        "field-name": "txtInformationOwner",
        "field-text": "Information Owner",
        "required": true
      },
      {
        "type": "text",
        "field-name": "txtProjectCode",
        "field-text": "Project Code",
        "required": true
      },
      {
        "type": "text",
        "field-name": "txtDelInformationOwner",
        "field-text": "Delegated Information Owner",
        "required": false
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "StepNumber": 2,
    "StepName": "Data Details"
  }
]
```

}
}

Thats the json file that i am using.  Getting the list of steps is easy.  Am i wrong for attempting a foreach inside a foreach to retrieve all the fields per step?

How do i get the list of Fields per Step otherwise?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some `Step` you don't have any `Fields`, so you will get `NullReferenceException`. You need to add validtion like:

```
@foreach (var step in Model.FormAttributes.Steps)
{
  @if (step.Fields != null && step.Fields.Any())
  {
       <li>@step.Fields.Count()</li>
       @foreach (var field in step.Fields)
       {
        ....
       }
  }
  else
  {
     <li>0</li>
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you and it is very much appreciated.

Comment: Glad to have been of help